# detect where a redirect wants to go with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a flash plugin. If I'm on that page, I don't want to post a message if the user wont to leaf it without saving it...:

```
if(/containers/.test(document.location.href)){
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
      return exit_text;  
    };
}
```

This works fine, except that I if i save the content in the flash plugin. In that case I don't want to show up that message. How can I detect the url within the onbeforeunload method? That way I can descide when to post the method!

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 0):

Only return a value in your onbeforeunload function if you want the prompt to show up:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if(/containers/.test(document.location.href)
        return exit_test;
}
```

If you want to check the *destination* URL you are out of luck. However, you can still set a variable when the user clicks the link which will got to that URL and then check on that variable.

Comment: that doesn't work, because document.location.href is the actual page name and not the one, witch it will be redirected to.